# What are the consequences of changing a symbol from .globl to .weak?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86

After having spent some time on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543901/ftrace-system-crash-when-changing-current-tracer-from-function-graph-via-echo), a user introduced me to an email thread concerning the below issue:

> [[PATCH] ftrace/x86: Fix function graph tracer reset path](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/5/13/327)
>
> > On my system, simply enabling and disabling function graph tracer can
> >     crash the kernel.  I don't know how it worked until now.
> >
> > The `ftrace_disable_ftrace_graph_caller()` modifies jmp instruction at
> >     `ftrace_graph_call` assuming it's a 5 bytes near jmp (e9 ).
> >     However it's a short jmp consisting of 2 bytes only (eb ).  And
> >     `ftrace_stub()` is located just below the `ftrace_graph_caller` so
> >     modification above breaks the instruction resulting in kernel oops on
> >     the `ftrace_stub()` with the invalid opcode like below:

One solution for this issue is the following patch:

```
 diff --git a/arch/x86/kernel/mcount_64.S b/arch/x86/kernel/mcount_64.S
 index ed48a9f465f8..e13a695c3084 100644
 --- a/arch/x86/kernel/mcount_64.S
 +++ b/arch/x86/kernel/mcount_64.S
 @@ -182,7 +182,8 @@ GLOBAL(ftrace_graph_call)
    jmp ftrace_stub
  #endif

 -GLOBAL(ftrace_stub)
 +/* This is weak to keep gas from relaxing the jumps */
 +WEAK(ftrace_stub)
    retq
  END(ftrace_caller)
```

via https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/5/16/493

I do not understand what the effect is in replacing `GLOBAL(ftrace_stub)` with `WEAK(ftrace_stub)`.  Neither the comment included in the patch nor looking into [GLOBAL()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h#L49) and [WEAK()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/linkage.h#L90) have helped me understand why this solution works.

**My question, as the title suggest, is:**  What are the consequences of changing a symbol from .globl to .weak?  I would appreciate an answer that considers how replacing `GLOBAL(ftrace_stub)` to `WEAK(ftrace_stub)` could address the referenced problem.

Comment: [This link gives you what you need.](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/5/18/326)

Comment: @LPs "Declaring ftrace_stub as a weak call prevents gas from using two byte jumps to it" contains part of what I don't understand; namely, how does declaring ftrace_stub as weak prevent using two byte jumps?  edit: Jester's answer filled in the piece of information that I was missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `ftrace_stub` is defined in the current file, the assembler knows the distance and can use the shorter version of `jmp` that only has limited range.

If it's changed to `weak` that means the symbol might not resolve to the one in the current file, as other module may override it. The offset to that potential override is not known, hence the assembler must use the full range `jmp` which is what the patching code expects.